# How to solve NonNullPrimaryKeys validation then apply migration in ASP.NET Core + Authentication + SQLite?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, validation

I made db context for interract with Sqlite:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IdentityUserClaim<string>> IdentityUserClaim { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IdentityUserRole<string>> IdentityUserRole { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename = my.db");
    }
}
```

Then after try to apply migrations in Package Manage Console I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'IdentityUserRole' requires a primary key to be defined.
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel model)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SqliteModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)

Comment: Define a primary key on `IdentityUserRole`, as the error message suggests?

Comment: I can't add something to IdentityUserRole because it in `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores` library